# What does the line " OPEN C_1 for Q_STR using MIN_NBR" mean? What does using the bind variable mean in this context

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE SELECT_12(
    MIN_NBR    NUMBER ,
FIELD_NAME VARCHAR2 )
IS
TYPE cur_type
IS
  REF
  CURSOR;
    C_1 CUR_TYPE;
    QUERY_STR  VARCHAR2(1000);
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(1000);
  BEGIN
    Q_STR:= 'SELECT BORR_FST_NM from OCN_DM_DDS.' || field_name ||' WHERE MIN_NBR = :MINNBR';

OPEN C_1 FOR Q_STR USING MIN_NBR;
LOOP
  FETCH C_1 INTO FIRST_NAME;
EXIT
  WHEN C_1%NOTFOUND;


    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(FIRST_NAME);
  END LOOP;
  NULL;
END SELECT_12;
```

What is happening in the line OPEN C_1 FOR Q_STR USING MIN_NBR? What does open "using the bind variable" mean?

Comment: The code is running fine. I just had an conceptual gap with regard to the bind variable.

Comment: Did you try reading the Oracle [documentation?](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS629)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic SQL statement includes:

```
WHERE MIN_NBR = :MINNBR
```

The colon indicates a bind variable; it can be called anything really but it's often named to match either the column name or more usefully the PL/SQL local variable that will be used to set it.

When the dynamic statement is executed;

```
OPEN C_1 FOR Q_STR USING MIN_NBR;
```

there are two stages. First it is parsed by the optimiser which decides on the most efficient way to fulfil the query, and at that point it still uses the bind variable placeholder rather than a specific value for that column. So it may decide there's an index it can use, whatever the actual value, for example. (It's a bit more complicated than that, but that's the gist).

Then it actually runs the query, using the plan it already knows it needs, but using the specific value you supplied. It gets that from the `using` part - the PL/SQL `MIN_NBR` variable's value is used to find the actual rows you want.

So while it's similar to doing:

```
SELECT BORR_FST_NM from OCN_DM_DDS.field_name WHERE MIN_NBR = fixed_value
```

the bind variable allows the same plan to be used for multiple queries.

When the bind value changes the same plan can be used - Oracle doesn't have to do a 'hard parse' to figure out how best to do it, it does a 'soft parse', recognises that it has seen the same query before, and uses the existing plan. This saves some time. It also stops the SQL cache being filled up with lots of almost-identical queries.

Answer (score 0):

In your dynamic sql you have `MIN_NBR = :MINNBR'`, where `:MINNBR` is the bind variable. You need to pass a value into the bind variable in order to make your query work when you run it - that's what the `USING MIN_NBR` part is doing.

It's saying pass the value of the `MIN_NBR` variable into the `:MINNBR` bind variable.